# search for string and echo only that line only?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, grep

Is it possible to search for a string and if it exists keep that line only...the full line and not just the string? I have two comma delimited data variables. What I would like to do is loop through my $data variable and use col2 of it as a search item. Then search the $example variable and if it finds the match then prepend some data to that line only. Below this prepends the data to the correct thing but it is printing out twice because  in this case there are two items. It would be nice to say don't print anything unless it is a match and then print that whole line

```
#!/bin/bash
data="item,thing
item2,thing2"

example="a,lot,of,thing,in,this,csv
big,foot,lives,next,to,me,yikes"

echo "$data" | while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
do
echo "$example" | sed "s/$col1/$col2,$col1/i"                                                                            
done
```

I have tried making col2 an array key but I wasn't successful with it. Maybe because I'm on a Mac and from what I read it ships with an older version of Bash.

Comment: Maybe you want a sed script like: "/$col1/s/^/$col2,/"

Comment: @VaughnCato - my sed script works above to do exactly what I want it just adds more data than the exact thing I want.

Comment: The way your script is, it will print every line, but putting the search at the beginning, it will only print matching lines.

Comment: @VaughnCato: The pattern at the beginning doesn't make any odds; you'd need the `-n` and `p` (print) command to make a difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  True, guess I'm tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `sed` to print unless you request it to, then you write:

```
... | sed -n "/$col1/{s/$col1/$col2,$col1/i; p}"
```

I'm assuming that the `i` suffix is meaningful to your dialect of `sed`; it isn't standard.  The `-n` means 'do not print automatically'.  The `/$col1/` looks for the pattern; when it is found, the commands in the braces are executed — your substitute operation and then 'print the line'.

Note that your pattern `item` would match `nitemare` if that appeared in `$example`.

Comment: the `i` stands for ignore case. is it possible to put ignore case on the thing your looking for...so in this case `sed -n "/$col1/IGNORE_CASE/{s/...`?

Comment: A case-insensitive search modifier such as your (hypothetical?) `i` would be nice, occasionally, but AFAIK, isn't available even in GNU `sed`.  You'd have to use Perl (or Python) to get to that functionality.  Note that there is an `s2p` program distributed with Perl to convert `sed` scripts into Perl scripts.  You could use that without the modifier, then edit the Perl script to add it.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I converted the strings to upper so there is no problem and it works now. Thanks a lot. Never knew about -n or p before. So much to learn!

Comment: `/REGEXP/I` - "The 'I' modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which causes the REGEXP to be matched in a case-insensitive manner." It works for selector regexes as well as the substitution shown in your answer. It must be an upper-case "I" for the former and can be either case for the latter.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Either I misread the manual I have (GNU `sed` 4.2, circa 2003; not modern) or the manual I have doesn't mention it (is too old, probably).  Thanks for the information.  I'm not surprised to find that it is supported by (modern) GNU.